# Ошибка средств компоновщика LNK2019

Tags: c++, компиляция, компоновщик

Заезженный до ужаса вопрос, и тем не менее. В компановщике дополнительные зависимости указаны, заголовки подключены а самое главное - *.dll файл отлично собирается под х86 если же поменять на х64 (и больше вообще ничего не трогать) тут же падают ошибки. Поменял обратно на х86 - компилится без проблем. В чем тут может быть дело ? Debug или Realise - без разницы.

> Ошибка LNK2001 неразрешенный внешний символ "luaL_openlib"
>
> Ошибка LNK2001 неразрешенный внешний символ "lua_pushstring"

Comment: Компоновщик о dll ничего не знает, он же с lib-файлами работает. Может у вас для x64-сборки подключается x86-lib-файл?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов думаете сложность в подключаемых .lib? как проверить их разрядность ?

Comment: Предполагаю что да, в них. Как проверить разрядоность я не знаю, в lib-файлах я четких маркеров не вижу. Попробуйте собрать lib именно под x64 и подключать его

Comment: `собрать lib именно под x64` как это сделать ? у меня есть только `lua5.1.lib` и заголовочные файлы - мне пересобрать `lua5.1.lib` ?

Comment: Если у вас только один lib-файл - да, проблема в нем. Придется пересобирать.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов т.е. нужно искать исходники .lib и пересобрать на х64 ?

Comment: Да. Иначе, считайте, не сделать.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов заголовочные файлы тоже менять?

Comment: Нет, исходный код (и заголовки) должны быть (если авторы хорошо написали) совместимы и с x86 и с x64

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов спасибо. буду пробовать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема в том, что подключаемый lib-файл содержит 32-битный код, который, разумеется, не подходит для линковки с 64-битным приложением. Нужно добыть или собрать 64-битный lib-файл и для сборки 64-битного приложения использовать его.